# the translation operator associated with the Bessel operator

Tags: definite-integrals, operator-theory, bessel-functions

the  translation operator  associated with the Bessel operator is  given by: $$\tau_x^{\nu} f(y) = \frac{\Gamma(\nu+1)}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma\left(\nu+\frac{1}{2}\right)} \int_{0}^\pi f\left(\sqrt{x^2+ y^2-2 xy\cos(\theta) }\right)(\sin(\theta))^{2v} \,d\theta.$$
Show that there exists a function $W(x,y,.)$ s.t  $$\tau_x^{\nu} f(y)=\int^{\infty}_{0}f(t)W(x,y,.)d\mu$$ where $d\mu(x)=\frac{x^{2v+1}}{2^v \Gamma(v+1)}dx.$
Any hints please.[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.